# Draw a skyplot with calculated ECEF values (in meters)

Tags: c#, gps

I have [ECEF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) values that I calculated from [ephemeris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeris) [subframes](http://www.kowoma.de/en/gps/data_composition.htm) 2/3.  Using this information, I'd like to place these values on a skyplot based on my current location.  I'm using a C# picture box for my skyplot image, and a custom control to show the dot and [SV](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Space-Vehicle-%28SV%29.html) [PRN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_noise).

I am struggling in these areas:

1. How to merge the ECEF information with my current location to provide a useful x,y for my skyplot.
2. How to determine the bounds of my drawing.  Currently i estimate that from edge to center of my drawing is 90 pixels.  So i attempted to do some scaling 90 / 20,000,000 (max distance for satellite, guessed), then multiplied that by my ECEF.x, and ECEF.y values.

I'd appreciate any help.
Thanks,
Jason